# How to dynamically set SMTP settings from UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Currently I have set below settings in `server.js` file to send mail to user via gmail SMTP.

```
//EMAIL SETTINGS
smtp = {
    username: "***@gmail.com",
    password: '***',
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465
  }

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
```

and I have to restart server if my client says that they have to change the address.

is there any dynamic way to set the SMTP settings from UI Store it in DB and then whenever user sends email, db values are picked up?

Comment: load them from a file, and in the ui modify that file

Comment: this is not possible because, there are going be multiple user who have their specific SMTP settings. Even users get added dynamically.

Comment: can you support your idea with some rough code?

Comment: this is basic variable passing and storing, its not diffcult, i would need to see the rest of the code to be able to show you something

Comment: I believe overwriting `process.env.MAIL_URL` is not fiber-safe. If all your users have different SMTP credentials, you might have to look for an alternative to Meteor's built-in email solution.

Comment: I don't think this is doable in the base email package.

Comment: @Michel Floyd: thank you so much. Can you suggest another package?